# C#: finding class fields in a List

Tags: c#, list, generic-collections

I have the following code:

```
class exampleClass
{
    int var1;
    int var2;
    string var3
}

List<exampleClass> myList = new List<exampleClass>()

myList.Add(new exampleClass { var1 = 10, var2 = 100, var3 = "a"});
myList.Add(new exampleClass { var1 = 20, var2 = 200, var3 = "b"});
etc.
```

If I would like to find the index # of the object in the List where var1 = 20, how do I go about doing that (in this case, var1 = 20 is in myList[1])?

I tried using Contain() but came up with errors.

And on a related subject, assuming each value of var1 is unique, would it be simply faster if I use a Dictionary with var1 as the key instead. Thanks.

Comment: "assuming each value of var1 is unique, would it be simply faster if I use a Dictionary with var1 as the key instead" Don't know for sure about faster, but it'd definitely be much more straightforward.

Comment: Why are you looking for the index?  Are you looking to sort it or something, or just retrieve it?

Comment: Retrieving it. I could do the same using Dictionary<int,myClass> and using var1 as the key, but was wondering if I could avoid building a dictionary for each list I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int index = myList.FindIndex(x => x.var1 == 20);
```

Comment: btw, `FindIndex` is not in LINQ, but simply in `System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 2):

faster is a very relative term.  It always depends on the number of objects in your collection.  It would probably be easier and make more sense though.

Using your example:

```
class exampleClass
{
    int var1;
    int var2;
    string var3
}

List<exampleClass> myList = new List<exampleClass>()

myList.Add(new exampleClass { var1 = 10, var2 = 100, var3 = "a"});
myList.Add(new exampleClass { var1 = 20, var2 = 200, var3 = "b"});

var dict = myList.ToDictionary(k => k.var1);
exampleClass item1 = dict[20];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = myList.FindIndex(val => val.Var1 == 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [full article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/01/06/c.net-ndash-finding-an-itemrsquos-index-in-ienumerablelttgt.aspx) on doing just that. It offers up several solutions depending on your need.

Comment: wow, thanks for the link. Some of the stuff in there is beyond my rudimentary C# understanding, but it gave me pointers for further research.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) method to retrieve the object (or [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) to retrieve all objects):

```
myList.Find(x => x.var1 == 20);
```

Or the [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) to retrieve its index in the `List`:

```
myList.FindIndex(x => x.var1 == 20);
```

Comment: `Find()` returns an actual object, he wants the index.

Comment: @Zero21xxx: Right, `FindIndex` then.